# How to reconnect socket after a passive network switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

So I have a Swift client, Node.js server, and am using socket.io. I have an issue where when the user changes from WiFi to LTE (passively, if they turn off wifi manually it works fine) while being connected to the server, for some reason they don't reconnect to the server (just hit a ping timeout). I've tried increasing ping timeout to 50 seconds with no effect. My users interact with each other while being connected to the same room so this is a big issue.

My connection code on the client-side looks like this:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient?
fileprivate var manager: SocketManager?

func establishConnection(_ completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let socketUrlString: String = serverURL
    self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: socketUrlString)!, config: [.forceWebsockets(true), .log(false), .reconnects(true), .extraHeaders(["id": myDatabaseID])])
    self.socket = manager?.defaultSocket
    self.socket?.connect()
        //self.socket?.on events go here
}
```

On the client side, my connection code looks like:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  pingTimeout: 10000
});

io.on('connection', onConnection);

function onConnection(socket){
  let headerDatabaseID = socket.handshake.headers.id
  //in the for loop below, I essentially disconnect any socket that has the same database ID as the one that just connected (in this case, when a client is in a room with other clients, 
  //and then he/she switches from WiFi to LTE, the client reconnects to the socket server and this removes the old connection from the room it was in)
  for (let [id, connectedSocket] of io.sockets.sockets) {
    if (connectedSocket.databaseID == headerDatabaseID && socket.id != id) {
      connectedSocket.disconnect()
      break
    }
  }
//socket.on() events here
}
```

My issue is this--how do I go about reconnecting the client when it makes the passive network switch (WiFi -> LTE or vice versa)? I thought that just adding .reconnects(true) would work but for some reason, it's not...

Please let me know if I can be more detailed/helpful or if you'd like to see other codes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution to you problem can be either simple or complex; that depends on your requirements. I assume that each chat room has its own ID.

If you store that ID in memory on the device, when the user reconnects, you can have the socket reconnect to the room ID you had last and they will re-join that room. ****This is insecure.****

If rooms are protected and not public, someone may be able to connect to a room that they are not allowed in if they know/can guess the room ID. To solve that problem, you'd need to implement some sort of authentication or server side database that keep keep track of that sort of stuff.

Comment: I've tried storing the roomID in memory, but am running into a bit of a conundrum. I planned on storing a 'previousRoomID'. I'd need this variable to be set when the socket disconnects, so I can access the room id before it's no longer accessible. The problem is this: the socket disconnects immediately when the network changes, so the in the .cellular or .wifi cases of the switch statement, the room ID is already inaccessible.

Comment: @nickcoding2 I think you may need to store it like a global variable and not just one in the scope of the network type (Cellular or WiFi). So if you set the variable higher in the scope and then manipulate it from the lower parts of the scope, you can still access it even if their connection type changes.

Comment: I fixed that particular case (manual) of the issue on the backend. Now it works when the network switch is manual (i.e. user turns off wifi), but when the switch is automatic (i.e. user walks from area with wifi to area without wifi), the socket does NOT reconnect. Any ideas?

Comment: @nickcoding2 Hmm... I think that may be the fault of the AnthonyR's/Reachability's solution you've implemented. At least that's what I suspect...

Comment: See, I think this is mainly a problem with the implementation of his socket.io instance-- although, with regards to namespacing the connection, it should be an auth token/cookie he generated by his api server and stored on his client. of course for dev, he can just use db ids for now.

Comment: When the app switches passively, I believe it's somehow caching his app and his state, meaning the socket.io instance is saved and not re-instantiated from component re-renders from a page refresh. This makes sense since there's no connections being made from this client on his server and socket.io's behavior doesn't allow reconnects when the instance failed to establish its connection handshake. However, on a deliberate network shift, the component is most likely re-rendering, therefore a new socket.io instance is made and thus is able to create a new connection-- without the breaking of conn

Comment: A network connection isn't rendered.... it is managed by the OS. The connection may get torn down & set up again depending on how the code works.

Comment: @nickcoding2 From what I understand, I've answered the question that you asked on this particular post. I believe your further questions go beyond the scope of this post, but please let me know if I'm wrong by that.

Comment: @ibrust, yes, i understand this. i'm referring to how the component code, which contains the socket.io instance that attempts the connection upon component instantiation(rendered), is re-rendered on deliberate network shifts, creating a new socket.io instance, ie, a new connection.

Comment: Rendering in a computer science context is the process of generating an image - a network connection, an instance of a socket, or any non-graphical component are not rendered. What is rendered is what is displayed on the screen.

Comment: I think you need to get out of the computer science context. We're talking about actual development here. And just because the component isn't visible to the screen doesn't mean it wasn't "rendered". If say you have a UI component that also has functions that create a new socket instance/connection, the code to perform the creation of a new socket instance and network connection exists in the rendered UI. So just because you can't see it, doesn't mean it isn't "rendered". You don't seem to have experience with regards to real world UI development contexts.

Comment: 'And just because the component isn't visible to the screen doesn't mean it wasn't "rendered"' Yes it does, that is exactly what it means. Go look up the definition of the word. People misuse words all the time, that is no reason that we shouldn't correct them and teach them what the words really mean. Communication is improved when you know what your words mean, and accurate communicating is important in software development (and relies on an understanding of computer science).

Comment: Why are we talking about computer science? Sounds like you just took an intro to computer science 101 course and are parroting terms you just read. Sure, you know the definition of "rendering" in a computer science context, but you're misusing the applicability of the term here since in this context the definition of the word changes. Lets put our computer science books down and focus on this specific context and problem at hand. I'm sure you felt good you were able to refer back to a computer science buzzword, but I think definitions change according to the context(relies on experience).

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/enabling-high-performance-metal-rendering-with-drawinggroup
^Here's an interesting article talking about rendering with Swift UI and React, stuff your computer science textbooks don't teach you. Anyways, any actual developer with experience understands that the definition/behavior of a "computer science" buzzword changes according to the context it's in. An array in JavaScript isn't the same as an Array in C, Rust. A component that's "rendered" to the screen can contain network calls, but that's not saying "the api call is being displayed"!

Comment: Another one: https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/swiftui-as-react-developer/
I think the issue with Computer Science being taught today is that it has little relevance to actual software development and doesn't prepare the college student properly to exceed since it's a lot of useless theory you never really apply in the real world. Sure, it helps prepare you for leetcode questions/interviews, but in the context of actually being able to develop an application-- it renders the inexperienced student completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the behavior varies based on whether the handoff is manual or passive it sounds like the issue is on the iOS client. I notice that you are using sockets - it seems to be some sort of custom sockets package, right? Is there a reason for using this? URLSession is a higher level implementation and it manages things like handoff.

There is something called Wifi assist, developed by apple, to manage handoff. It is part of the OS and manages this internally. According to apple: "Using URLSession and the Network framework already gives us the new WiFi assist benefits.". This was released in iOS 9, in Sept 2015.
But if you are using some other kind of sockets, whatever this "socketIOClient" is - especially packages developed prior to Sept 2015, you are probably bypassing Wifi assist. The latest version of SocketIO client I see was written in 2015 and it appears support for this package was discontinued when iOS 9 came out.

When the user manually changes the connection this is manually prompting the OS to tear down & reestablish the connection, whereas with passive tradeoff it normally relies on this Wifi Assist.

You could try to programmatically tear down & reestablish the connection when you detect that a passive handoff has occurred, but I wouldn't recommend this... for starters, it will make your code much messier. It will probably degrade the user experience. But worse, this may not be the only problem you run into using this outdated socketIO package. There's really no telling what kind of maintenance problems you will wind up with. Better to just refactor your code to use the up to date networking mechanisms provided by iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If `.reconnects(true)` isn't working, you can try to manually take care of the problem with Apple's Reachability. [This](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) may make it easier - it's the Reachability functionality "re-written in Swift with closures."

In your case, you might use it as such:

```
let reachability = try! Reachability()

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    if reachability.connection == .wifi {
        print("Reachable via WiFi")
        self.socket.disconnect();
        establishConnection() //this is your method defined in the question
    } else {
        print("Reachable via Cellular")
        self.socket.disconnect();
        establishConnection() //this is your method defined in the question
    }
}
reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
    print("Not reachable")
}

do {
    try reachability.startNotifier()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start notifier")
}
```